# getting username from form and search in github api

Tags: php, api, github

I'm trying to search a user using the Github api, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

My html form:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Buscar Usuario</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
  </div>  
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Procurar</button>
</form>
```

My php code:

```
<?php 
    function buscaUser()
    {
        $user=  $_GET['username'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url ="https://api.github.com/search/users?q=".$user;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump(json_decode($result));
    }
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: are you calling this `buscaUser` function somewhere?

Comment: echo the $user and check if it is coming right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu didn't call the **buscaUser()** anywhere

Do it this way:

```
<?php 
function buscaUser($user) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url ="https://api.github.com/search/users?q=".$user;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result));
}
?>
```

Then you can call the function and pass the submitted value:

```
<?php
    echo buscaUser($_GET['username']);
?>
```

Should do!